# java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.util.Date

Tags: java, mysql

I want to convert string date to date format for storing database table. The code below is not working. It is showing a **java.lang.ClassCastException**:

```
java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.util.Date Exception
```

*Code*

```
Date date = (Date)hmap.get("skillexpdate");
```

Answer (score 7):

You can use this code :

```
DateFormat simpleDateFormat=new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
java.sql.Date dutyDay = (java.sql.Date) simpleDateFormat.parse("There is String Date");
```

Answer (score 5):

Use [`SimpleDateFormat#parse()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) instead; you cannot directly cast a `String` instance into a `Date`.

Answer (score 1):

You can't simply cast. You need to use [SimpleDateFormat.parse()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) to convert `String` to `Date`.

Comment: SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");  Date date=formatter.parse(hmap.get("skillexpdate").toString());       i changed the code above format still it is showing same exception..

Comment: @Ajithlal: Parameter format changes based on what format your String is. For example if String is in format 2013-09-27, then your code in above comment will work fine.